# How to make nginx return the last server's response with proxy_next_upstream?

Tags: nginx

What is the behavior of proxy_next_upstream if it already tries all the upstream servers and all of them return errors? I want it to return the last server's error code, but it seems that nginx returns a 502 bad gateway in that case, or is there a config for that?

Comment: What errors they did return?

Comment: They return a 503 service unvailable